# .htaccess and rewrite of URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

We have the following example "ugly" URL:

```
https://some.uglyurl.com/directory/test.jsp?hotelid=1111&rateplanid=33333
```

we need to direct our customers to the above URL using our own domains URL as the address - so it would look something like:

```
https://www.PrettyURL.com/reservations?hotelid=1111&rateplanid=33333
```

The idea being that the address our customers "see" is a nice looking "familiar" URL to them.  Is this possible in .htaccess?  We would tack on various variables AFTER the test.jsp in the ugly URL - so it can't just be a fixed set of variables.

many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that worked for me:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.prettyurl.com$
RewriteRule ^reservations$ https://uglyURL.com/istay/istay.jsp?%2 [QSA,L]
```

It works exactly as I needed it.

Many thanks to Gumbo and others for all their help.

Answer (score 2):

If you were just using plain HTTP, you could set up the *pretty URL* server as a [proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) that passes every request to the *ugly URL* server and the response back to the client:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pretty\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^reservations$ http://ugly.example.com/directory/test.jsp [L,P]
```

But as you’re using HTTPS, it is not possible without getting an error message, that the certificate’s host name is not correct.

Comment: I set this - but I'm losing the 2nd variable (in this case "&rateplanid=33333".  When I enter the pretty url with those variables, I am redirected to the ugly url site which doesn't appear to take the second set of variables into consideration - as if it never received the info to do so.

Comment: Do you modify the query of the URL? If so, add the QSA flag to get the original query automatically appended to the new URL.

Comment: not sure I understand, what is a "QSA flag". Sorry I'm bit of a noob with this! :) here is what I have:
<br><br>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.prettyurl.com$
RewriteRule ^/reservations$ https://booking.uglyurl.com/istay/istay.jsp [L,P]

Comment: The comma separated list in square brackets at the end of the directives is called flags. And if you want to use this rule in the .htaccess file in you document root, remove the leading slash of your patterns. That directory dependent slash is removed from the URL path before testing the patterns and added again after applying a rule.

Comment: the thing is...the first set of variables (ie. ?hotelid=1111) is being transferred over but the SECOND set (i.e. &rateplanid=33333) is not.

Comment: Then try this rule: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pretty\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]*&)*(hotelid=[^&]*)
RewriteRule ^reservations$ http://ugly.example.com/directory/test.jsp?%2 [L,P]

Comment: Did as you stated BUT it's still not accepting/carrying forward the 2nd set of variables (for whatever reason it discards it) - when we actually NEED them to be there. (btw...thank you so much for your help with this. :)

Comment: we input prettyurl.com/reservations?hotelid=1111&rateplanid=2222 and it goes to uglyurl.com/istay/istay.jsp?hotelid=1111 - which is NOT quite what we want it to do.  we need both hotelid and rateplanid to follow through.

Comment: Then append it with `…?%{QUERY_STRING}` to the new address.